# UILocalNotification with non default timezone

Tags: iphone, timezone, uilocalnotification

I have been trying to use UILocalNotification and setting timezone to some other timezone than my default.

The purpose is to do something like:
-User will schedule an alert with time and timezone
-Show alert when that timezone becomes specified time.

In more verbal description, let say I live in LosAngeles and my gf is in Chicago.  I want to set up an alert when chicago is 7am, for weekdays.

For one alert, I can do without timezone, to do absolute time.  But I want to allow users to set repeat flags, in which case I can't seem to do - I tried setting localnotification's timezone property to chicago as above example, however the local notification will not fire.

I logged the uinocalnotification during serialization process, and here's one output:

```
"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0xfb25a50>{fire date = 2011-02-06 06:02:00 -0800, time zone = America/Chicago (CST) offset -21600, repeat interval = 16, next fire date = 2011-02-06 08:02:00 -0800}"
```

I set firedate for 9:02am chicago absolute time, and timezone to cst - and the log does mention that the fire date is indeed 06:02 my local time. However, nothing happens.  Also, next fire date is weird since it should be +1 day, not +2 hrs.

Here's how I set this up:
    Class classUILocalNotification = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

```
if (classUILocalNotification != nil) {
    id note = [[classUILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSString *body = @"body message";       
    switch (repeatflag) {
        case 1: [note setRepeatInterval:NSDayCalendarUnit]; break;
        case 2: [note setRepeatInterval:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit]; break;
        case 3: [note setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit]; break;
        case 4: [note setRepeatInterval:NSMonthCalendarUnit]; break;
        case 5: [note setRepeatInterval:NSYearCalendarUnit]; break; 
        default: break;
    }
    [note setFireDate:dt];
    [note setAlertBody:body];
    [note setTimeZone:timezone];                
    [note setHasAction:NO];
}
```

This seems like some unknown behavior.  Anyone have a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Post some more code so that we can check the exact problem is!!

Comment: hi kongofbliss, thanks for reply.  There seems to be issue with UILocalNotification (UILN) when you set it to fire with anything other than current tz.  I haven't figured out exactly what, but when tz not current tz, firing date seems to get mixed up in my testing (ios4.0.2).

To get around this, I just had to schedule uilocalnotification without timezone info set.  So, date is interpreted as absolute, and fires correctly.  

By the way, for anyone trying to do this, there's bug with ios4.0 when you uninstall the app, and reinstall app - UILN set from previous install will show up in new app.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with UILocalNotification when using non-local timezone. The first event fired is fired for the correct date and time and timezone. However, subsequent events fire for the given date and time in your local timezone instead of the one set in the setTimeZone method. [iOS 6.1]